# multiple parameter on DatabaseContext class constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to inject and use ILogger from DatabaseContext in asp.net core.
And I want to manage the context using a Contextpool.
However, when I try to inject two dependencies including Ilogger, I get the following error.

> The DbContext of type 'DatabaseContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions or has more than one constructor.

How can I get an `Ilogger` injected?

This is my database context classes constructor

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
 
    
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options, ILogger<DatabaseContext> logger) : base(options)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

and setting database context pool setting code on `program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<DatabaseContext>((provider,options) =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(appConfiguration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection"))
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .EnableDetailedErrors();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the AddDbContextPool, you should query the required services instead of injecting it.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
   {
       private readonly ILogger _logger;

       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options )
           : base(options)
       {
           _logger = this.GetService<ILogger<ApplicationDbContext>>();
           _logger.LogError("test");
       }

   }
```

Result:

[image]